# Codeigniter Query Builder One to many

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to calculate the total revenue for one day.
The result should be
96.5 Euros in treatments
510 Euros in arrangements
Total : 606.5 Euro

The query works when only selecting treatments or arrangements but does not work when both are being joined.

This is the query:

```
function getTotalRevenueToday($user_id) {
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    $this->db->select('agenda.agenda_id,SUM(t.price) as ttotal,SUM(a.price) as atotal');
    $this->db->from('agenda');
    $this->db->join('agenda_treatments at', 'at.agenda_id = agenda.agenda_id');
    $this->db->join('treatments t', 't.treatment_id = at.treatment_id');
    $this->db->join('agenda_arrangements aa', 'aa.agenda_id = agenda.agenda_id');
    $this->db->join('arrangements a', 'a.arrangement_id = aa.arrangement_id');
    $this->db->where('agenda.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('agenda.date =', $today);

    $Q = $this->db->get();
    return $Q;
}
```

So there is a agenda table that has a agenda_treatments id ,
than there is a agenda_treatments table that contains the agenda_id,
than there is a treatments table that contains the treatment_id from agenda_treatments
Same for agenda_arrangements

The goal is to calculate a total of treatments.price and arrangements.price.

I have made queries like this earlier, but I believe that there is a group_by missing here somewhere.

This is what it returns now[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried left joins?

Comment: Yes, still returns the same result

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? Does it return an error ? Or a wrong result ? Or nothing ?

Comment: Just wrong results, query works tho

Comment: $this->db->group_by('agenda_id');

Comment: Does (and should) it return just one line ? Have you tried grouping by `agenda.agenda.id` ? or by `agenda.user_id`?

Comment: Yes, the code currently groups it by agenda_id and user_id has been tried too, still the same. But the results are 100% wrong